# How to pass key/value to the Lambda function with signature S3Event,Object?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I want to call a Lambda function(Java) through a scheduler. I want the function does different things based some condition. I want to call the function for every 1 minute, for every 5 minutes, and for once in a day.

I want to have 3 rules(CloudWatch Events) attached to this function. For each rule, the function works differently.

I need to pass some key/value to the function everything it got invoked. Based on the key/value condition, the function acts differently.

How to pass key/value everything the function is invoked through the scheduler?
thanks
Srini

Answer (score 0):

If your function requires some dynamic parameters, you can have a logic inside lambda that will pull / generate necessary parameters.

If you just need to pass different but static arguments to the function based on the execution time,  then use "Input" option in EventScheduler. So for 1 min it would have 1 set of params, for 5 another and so on ...

Comment: How to read those input params in my Java lambda function? My function is with signature : handleRequest(S3Event input, Context context)

Comment: Anyway, I replaced S3Event to my custom class. Now I am able to get the params.